# How big are my disk arrays?

Tags: storage, hardware, solaris, zfs, sunos

On my SunOS 5.10 host are there 3 Sun 6140 disk arrays, and I would like to know the disk capacities.

According to `zpool list` do I have a 5TB and 16TB pool. `format` shows me only 12 disks

```
c2t1d31: configured with capacity of 16.00MB
c3t4d31: configured with capacity of 16.00MB
c5t4d31: configured with capacity of 16.00MB
c6t1d31: configured with capacity of 16.00MB

AVAILABLE DISK SELECTIONS:
       0. c0t0d0 <LSILOGIC-LogicalVolume-3000 cyl 65533 alt 2 hd 16 sec 136>
          /pci@780/pci@0/pci@9/scsi@0/sd@0,0
       1. c2t1d31 <SUN-UniversalXport-0660 cyl 8 alt 2 hd 64 sec 64>
          /pci@7c0/pci@0/pci@8/SUNW,qlc@0/fp@0,0/ssd@w200400a0b826ab41,1f
       2. c3t4d31 <SUN-UniversalXport-0660 cyl 8 alt 2 hd 64 sec 64>
          /pci@7c0/pci@0/pci@8/SUNW,qlc@0,1/fp@0,0/ssd@w200700a0b826e4f3,1f
       3. c4t600A0B800026E4F20000056E49377BFCd0 <SUN-CSM200_R-0660-1.65TB>
          /scsi_vhci/ssd@g600a0b800026e4f20000056e49377bfc
       4. c4t600A0B800026E4F20000056F49377C9Cd0 <SUN-CSM200_R-0660-1.65TB>
          /scsi_vhci/ssd@g600a0b800026e4f20000056f49377c9c
       5. c4t600A0B800026E4F20000057049377D00d0 <SUN-CSM200_R-0660-1.65TB>
          /scsi_vhci/ssd@g600a0b800026e4f20000057049377d00
       6. c4t600A0B800026E6960000044A4637FB93d0 <SUN-CSM200_R-0660-1.82TB>
          /scsi_vhci/ssd@g600a0b800026e6960000044a4637fb93
       7. c4t600A0B800026E6960000056049377BCBd0 <SUN-CSM200_R-0660-1.99TB>
          /scsi_vhci/ssd@g600a0b800026e6960000056049377bcb
       8. c4t600A0B800026E6960000043C4637FA2Dd0 <SUN-CSM200_R-0660-1.82TB>
          /scsi_vhci/ssd@g600a0b800026e6960000043c4637fa2d
       9. c4t600A0B800026E6960000055C49377AB7d0 <SUN-CSM200_R-0660-1.99TB>
          /scsi_vhci/ssd@g600a0b800026e6960000055c49377ab7
      10. c4t600A0B800026E6960000055E49377B4Fd0 <SUN-CSM200_R-0660-1.99TB>
          /scsi_vhci/ssd@g600a0b800026e6960000055e49377b4f
      11. c4t600A0B800026E696000004444637FB39d0 <SUN-CSM200_R-0660-1.82TB>
          /scsi_vhci/ssd@g600a0b800026e696000004444637fb39
      12. c4t600A0B800029015800000539461071B7d0 <SUN-CSM200_R-0660-1.36TB>
          /scsi_vhci/ssd@g600a0b800029015800000539461071b7
      13. c4t600A0B80002901580000052B46106563d0 <SUN-CSM200_R-0660-1.82TB>
          /scsi_vhci/ssd@g600a0b80002901580000052b46106563
      14. c4t600A0B80002901580000053346107101d0 <SUN-CSM200_R-0660-1.82TB>
          /scsi_vhci/ssd@g600a0b80002901580000053346107101
      15. c5t4d31 <SUN-UniversalXport-0660 cyl 8 alt 2 hd 64 sec 64>
          /pci@7c0/pci@0/pci@9/SUNW,qlc@0/fp@0,0/ssd@w200500a0b826ab41,1f
      16. c6t1d31 <SUN-UniversalXport-0660 cyl 8 alt 2 hd 64 sec 64>
          /pci@7c0/pci@0/pci@9/SUNW,qlc@0,1/fp@0,0/ssd@w200600a0b826e4f3,1f
```

and what is strange here is that `format` claims the disks are larger than 1TB, which can not be the case according to the [6140 datasheet](http://www.crocom.com.pl/ulotki/6140.pdf).

`/etc/hosts` contain

```
#6140 Disk array
10.0.68.65
10.0.68.66
10.0.68.67
10.0.68.68
```

where all can be ping'ed.

I don't see any RAID with `zpool status`

```
  pool: dat0
 state: ONLINE
 scan: none requested
config:

        NAME                                     STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        dat0                                     ONLINE       0     0     0
          c4t600A0B800026E6960000044A4637FB93d0  ONLINE       0     0     0
          c4t600A0B800026E6960000043C4637FA2Dd0  ONLINE       0     0     0
          c4t600A0B800026E696000004444637FB39d0  ONLINE       0     0     0
          c4t600A0B800026E6960000055C49377AB7d0  ONLINE       0     0     0
          c4t600A0B800026E4F20000056E49377BFCd0  ONLINE       0     0     0
          c4t600A0B800026E6960000055E49377B4Fd0  ONLINE       0     0     0
          c4t600A0B800026E4F20000056F49377C9Cd0  ONLINE       0     0     0
          c4t600A0B800026E4F20000057049377D00d0  ONLINE       0     0     0
          c4t600A0B800026E6960000056049377BCBd0  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors

  pool: dat1
 state: ONLINE
 scan: none requested
config:

        NAME                                     STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        dat1                                     ONLINE       0     0     0
          c4t600A0B800029015800000539461071B7d0  ONLINE       0     0     0
          c4t600A0B80002901580000053346107101d0  ONLINE       0     0     0
          c4t600A0B80002901580000052B46106563d0  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

**Question**

As each 6140 have 16 disks, I would expect to see 3x16 disks, but I only see 12 which larger capacity then the datasheet allows, and I don't see any raid configured. And way are the reported disk sizes so different from disk to disk?

How do I find the disks real capacity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're expecting a JBOD, but it appears that this might be set up as a SAN, and you're seeing LUNs. You should check the 6140s themselves.

Comment: Yes it is a SAN. Why would it be configured with LUNs and not just as a JBOD?

Comment: Terminology matters here- a SAN is technically the entire network for the storage- all the switching, storage controllers, and client hookups (like HBAs and blade interconnects). A JBOD can live in a SAN, but rarely does. A JBOD is almost always directly attached to a server, and relies on the server's RAID card to control the disks. A more commonly seen setup is where the disk controller has its own raid management system and provides virtual disks (LUNs) to whatever servers connect to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you think the OS is lying to you, you can run this

```
zfs list
```

It will show you how much space ZFS has available from those disks.