# Removing all hw raid from Sun server

Tags: hardware, storage, solaris, zfs, sunos

[This](https://serverfault.com/questions/619128/how-big-are-my-disk-arrays) post is about the same server as this post, where multiple disks were in a LUN, and then ZFS was used to make the ZFS pools.

I would like to use the 6140 disk arrays as JBOD's on either Linux or OmniOS, so now I have deleted all RAID pools using the Sun StorageTek web interface. I know there are two hardware raid controllers.

When I do

```
# format
Searching for disks...done

c2t1d31: configured with capacity of 16.00MB
c3t4d31: configured with capacity of 16.00MB
c5t4d31: configured with capacity of 16.00MB
c6t1d31: configured with capacity of 16.00MB


AVAILABLE DISK SELECTIONS:
       0. c0t0d0 <LSILOGIC-LogicalVolume-3000 cyl 65533 alt 2 hd 16 sec 136>
          /pci@780/pci@0/pci@9/scsi@0/sd@0,0
       1. c2t1d31 <SUN-UniversalXport-0660 cyl 8 alt 2 hd 64 sec 64>
          /pci@7c0/pci@0/pci@8/SUNW,qlc@0/fp@0,0/ssd@w200400a0b826ab41,1f
       2. c3t4d31 <SUN-UniversalXport-0660 cyl 8 alt 2 hd 64 sec 64>
          /pci@7c0/pci@0/pci@8/SUNW,qlc@0,1/fp@0,0/ssd@w200700a0b826e4f3,1f
       3. c5t4d31 <SUN-UniversalXport-0660 cyl 8 alt 2 hd 64 sec 64>
          /pci@7c0/pci@0/pci@9/SUNW,qlc@0/fp@0,0/ssd@w200500a0b826ab41,1f
       4. c6t1d31 <SUN-UniversalXport-0660 cyl 8 alt 2 hd 64 sec 64>
          /pci@7c0/pci@0/pci@9/SUNW,qlc@0,1/fp@0,0/ssd@w200600a0b826e4f3,1f
Specify disk (enter its number):
```

This surprises me a bit, as I would have expected to see all 16*3 disks ready to be used by zfs.

**Question**

Why don't I see all the physical disks, now that I have deleted the raid pools in the web interface?

Are (these) arrays JBOD's by nature, or do I need to do something to them now, when they are still connected to the Sun server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't see the LUNs from the array because you deleted them. The 6140 is not a JBOD array.  LUNs have to be created - and mapped - to be visible.  A 6140 is effectively an entire storage server, with built-in redundancy if you have one with two controllers.

Depending on the features licensed for your 6140, there are a lot of different options.

How are they connected?  You do not want to disconnect them from whatever device is managing them.

Read [the admin guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19381-01/819-5050-10/819-5050-10.pdf).

Comment: Ever feel like [you're being trolled](http://serverfault.com/users/208796/jasmine-lognnes)?

Comment: @ewwhite - Well, if it's a troll it's pretty indistinguishable from many of the  questions I've fielded about arrays like the 6140 over the years.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Ok, this is super interesting! There are 3 6140's, but in the  web interface, they only appear as san1 and san2. san2 is 16x500GB + 16*1TB disks. Is it how the arrays are cabled to the server, I should explain?

Comment: Three 6140s, or two 6140s with one of them having an expansion tray of 16 disks?  Look at the back.  A 6140 itself has one or two controller modules with multiple fiber channel and ethernet connections.  An expansion tray has a much smaller number of fiber channel connections and no ethernet connections, and if it's operational it will be connected via fiber channel to the 6140 controller(s).  What are you using to manage the 6140s?  Sun's/Oracle's CAM or some version of LSI's SANtricity?